# Mezclar dos arreglos en c++ con for

Tags: c++, array

he estado estudiando un poco de estructura de datos y al momento de querer hacer este ejercicio (que me piden con bucles for), pero al momento de hacerlo, simplemente no se me ocurre cómo llevar acabo los demás arreglos.

Estos dos son los arreglos específicos:

`int K[4]={7,18,3,10}; int L[4]={3,6,9,7};`

queriendo que éstos dos arreglos queden como {7,3,18,6,3,9,10,7}

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
   for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            if (i>=1){

            i++;
        }
        M[i]=K[i];

        for (j=0;j<4;j++){
            if (j>=1){

            j++;
        }
            M[j]=L[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    cout<<"{";
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        cout<<" "<<M[i]<<", ";
    }

    cout<<"}\n\n";
```

Pero, al momento de compilarlo, me sale "{ 3, 18, 3, 7, 3, 6, 9, 7 }"

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se si te han solicitado resolver el ejercicio mediante bucles for anidados, pero me parece una forma más intuitiva realizarlo mediante bucles separados y con un contador a parte para la posición del array que junta los números.

```
int K[4]={7,18,3,10}; int L[4]={3,6,9,7}; 
int M[8];
int c = 0;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    M[c] = K[i];
    c+=2;
}
c=1;
for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
    M[c]=L[j];
    c+=2;
}

cout<<"{";
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    cout<<" "<<M[i]<<", ";
}

cout<<"}\n\n"; 
return 0;
```

U otra solución con un solo bucle:

```
int K[4]={7,18,3,10};
int L[4]={3,6,9,7}; 
int M[8];
int c = 0;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    M[c] = K[i];
    M[c+1] = L[i];
    c+=2;
}

cout<<"{";
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    cout<<" "<<M[j]<<", ";
}

cout<<"}\n\n"; 
return 0;
```

Notá que en tu código, el segundo bucle, se repite entero (4 veces) cada vez que ingresa al primer bucle! Por eso se te desordena todo.

Comment: Eres un crack. Estaba buscando la forma de cómo resolver este problema y en serio me diste la lógica para hacerlo. Muchas gracias, crack

Comment: El código tiene un error: la formación de destino debe ser de 8 posiciones, no 7.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que lo que necesitas es que la primera formación<sup>1</sup> se guarde en las posiciones pares y la segunda en las impares de la formación de destino:

```
int K[4] =     {7,  18,  3,  10};
//              |   |    |   |
//              0   2    4   6
//              |   |    |   |
//              v   v    v   v
// Queden como {7,3,18,6,3,9,10,7}
//                ^    ^   ^    ^
//                |    |   |    |
//                1    3   5    7
//                |    |   |    |
int L[4] =     {  3,   6,  9,   7};
```

Puedes hacer un bucle que apunte a los elementos de las formaciones `K` y `L` uno a uno mientras apunta los de la formación de destino de dos en dos, guardando `K` en el primero de la formación de destino y `L` en el segundo:

```
int destino[8];

for (int *k = K, *l = L, *d = destino, *end = k + 4; k != end; ++k, ++l, d += 2)
{
    *d = *k;
    *(d + 1) = *l;
}
```

Si hacemos una plantilla para esto, podemos aportar algo más de seguridad al código:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
void merge(T (&A)[SIZE], T (&B)[SIZE], T (&C)[SIZE + SIZE])
{
    for (T *a = A, *b = B, *c = C, *end = A + SIZE; a != end; ++a, ++b, c += 2)
    {
        *c = *a;
        *(c + 1) = *b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
    int b[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    int c[8];

    merge(a, b, c);

    for (const auto &v : c)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLasMwEDxbXzGlkPihQpO@QpwEktBDz82pxhRZVoMhlowtB9rgb3dXdij0sqOZ0ax2JavqTp6EPvb9baHlqc0VVoVpbK1EuWHMqrI6CUui/a6UFqXCgaOx@XLZFD/q0@L97eN1w86myFGq@qj8A/zJNkicnnI4tvvH9iNDNETTgF2Y92VqUDAUWGPLEWaEO0JJuCdUOnfONRND4GYNEmNEkeBUMg6JaI15wDzq5w3JUMTu6JODWeCEjISOdYwV2qIUhfaH5x0TSUo3LphxPHA8cbygi0cru1pzjkeOZ47FnyWTRRoz5o2r0yhukMApw0rS6IZat9ZgcsaSLBpo@D1pWovVCmdXppi6SK1sW2vcx6zr@18)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.